# Putting php variable with Guillemets inside meta tag with Guillemets

Tags: php

I have a meta tag for description that I fill in like this :

```
   echo '<meta property="og:description" html:="true" content="' . $var . '">';
```

with $var being text with some `"` in the text.
Oviously a `"` closes the content part which is problematic..

I can't do :

```
   <meta property="og:description" html:="true" content="<?php echo $var; ?>">
```

in my situtation.

I was wondering if they was a function for this type of situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`htmlspecialchars()` was what I was looking for !